# Methods of saving complex objects in C++

Tags: c++, object, serialization, save

I've always saved data by writing ASCII to files, that is,

```
param1 = value1
param2 = string string string
```

and loaded it with an annoying amount of parsing overhead. I just tried to up my programming game by writing an entire object to a binary file, a la

```
class Record {
    int par1;
    string par2;
    vector<string> par3;
    void saveRecord(string fName);
    void loadRecord(string fName);
}

Record::saveRecord() {
    ...
    fstream outFile(fName.c_str(), fstream::out | fstream::binary);
    outFile.write( (char*)this, sizeof(Record) );
    outFile.close();
}
```

etc etc.  But I found out this doesn't work because complex data types (e.g. string, vector) involve pointers whose values can't be stored this way.

**So it sounds like the options are**

**A) Write complicated serializing algorithms to convert every complex data-type to primitives, then save to binary; or**

**B) Just write everything to an ASCII file as per my initial strategy.**

The first method seems overly complex, and the second underly elegant.

**Are there other options?
Is there a standard procedure?**

Note: I have seen the boost::serialization library, which also looks very inelegant and oddly cumbersome--- that is, I would just write my own serialization methods instead, if that were the proper methodology.

Comment: If all your strings have a fairly small maximum length, you could store the string data inside your record object as fixed length `char` arrays. Otherwise, I'm afraid it's A or B or C) use an inelegant library...

Comment: it cant get much simpler than boost.serialization. And on a sidenote, how excactly do you write ASCII-files? Last time i checked everyone was using latin1, some win125X encoding, or utf8.

Comment: what about method B) using http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/ or similar?

Comment: @moooeeeep I hadn't heard of YAML before, it looks interested---and definitely a sufficient solution.  I'm not a professional of any sort, I'm largely interested in the process instead of the product---and thus avoid external libraries (etc) basically whenever possible.

Comment: @smerlin this is probably something you should be familiar with.  While the encoding sets you listed are the current standards for unicode-compliant character sets, ASCII refers specifically to a basic subset of commonly used (and often sufficient) characters.  When I said 'write to an ASCII file' I was explicitly saying that I'm writing very simple, human-readable data.  Try reading the relevant wikipedia articles---this is an important distinction.

Comment: @zhermes: my comment was sarcastic sorry for not making that clear enough. You should have been saying that you write text or non-binary data. Your statement that ASCII is often sufficent is out of place in todays time of globalization and the internet. Even latin1 is often insufficent.

Answer (score 3):

No. Use Boost.Serialization or Google Protocol Buffers. And yes, you have to write functions that will put and extract your data into/from the serialisation container. That's how it's done for robust solutions that are expected to actually work.

This way you gain versioning, compatibility and portability of your binary files. If you treat your data as bunch of bytes, and write/read everything, you won't be able to read old files when you change the structure, or when the file is written from a build with different padding/byte sizes/byte ordering.

It might work for simple stuff, but will break so fast you will just regret not doing it right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 strategies you mentioned

A) Write complicated serializing algorithms to convert every complex data-type to primitives, then save to binary; or

B) Just write everything to an ASCII file as per my initial strategy.

Are how its usually done. You are essentially creating your own file format. The most common paradigm is the chunk paradigm. When you save an object or set of objects, first you write an int representing the size of the object or "chunk" of data. And the next int representing the kind of object. You may want to include version information aswell if you care about supporting configurations that you save when a user upgrades their software.

Option A is useful when you care about the data being very exact, and it makes it easier to load/save problematically in c++. E.g. floats saved this way will be loaded with the exact same value as saved.

Option B is useful when you want to see what you are saving, and perhaps for a person to modify the data in some way by hand. Floats saved here, when loaded back will not be the exact same.

Try looking at other file formats for examples. Midi file format uses chunks paradigm, and has a streaming feature too, which uses option A. Wavefront "obj" file format is used in 3D application, for its simplicity which uses option B. Everything is readable in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with text based serialization, you could attempt to just override:

- `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Type& obj);` for serialization, and
- `std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Type& obj);` for deserialization.

The library already serializes and deserializes the primitive types, you don't need access to a class or template's innards to write your own overrides, and C++ programmers are already familiar with the concept.

For example, a serializer/deserializer for a `std::vector` could look something like:

```
template<class T, class Alloc>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec)
{   os << vec.size << '\n';
    for(std::vector<T, Alloc>::const_iterator i = vec.begin();
        i != vec.end(); ++i)
        os << *vec << '\n';
    return os;
}

template<class T, class Alloc>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, std::vector<T, Alloc>& vec)
{   vec.clear();
    size_t size = 0;
    is >> size;
    vec.reserve(size);
    while(size--)
    {   T temp;
        is >> temp;
        vec.push_back(temp);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Note that this approach has several restrictions (left as an exercise for the reader). It's your job to evaluate these and decide if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any standard procedure, it depends on the data you are storing. What you describe is the difference between a shallow and deep representation (much like a shallow or deep copy). I'd suggest planning a simplified serialisation mechanism for each class depending  on what is stored. As you point out, it is insufficient just to write out a byte representation of the memory when you have underlying elements that are not contiguous (or even part of) with the class instance.